# How to decrypt EFS encrypted files from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, encryption, data-recovery, efs

Because the [regular](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-cipherexe-for-command-line-encryption/) decrypt procedure with cipher **fails**, looking for alternatives.  Along the lines of this [exercise](https://www.hacking-lab.com/cases/7001-windows-security-disclose-a-windows-encrypted-file-efs/index.html):

> Goal
>
> You have succeeded once you know the content of the encrypted file...

Looking at [NTFS decrypt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ntfsdecrypt.8.html), my thinking is that something like Kali Linux will have utilities to fix this.

It seems to be valid keys which have expired.  Some files, not all, are encrypted.

I'm in early stages of research, just don't want to go down false paths.

Perhaps something like:

https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/howto-~-decrypt-EFS-files

although I also see:

> Linux
>
> It is possible to decrypt files using ntfsdecrypt tool. In this case,
>   you should get the private key first (by running cipher /x
>   filename.pfx on a Windows system).

https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Windows_Encrypted_File_System

-----------------update---------------------

I'll try the procedure outlined here first:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc512680(v=technet.10)

Comment: Even if the certificate has expired, an expired certificate, that would not prevent you from decrypting the files.  An expired certificate does not become unusable when it expires, only a certificate revocation, would cause that (even that can be avoided).

Comment: Unfortunately, the decrypt procedure doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with `ntfsdecrypt` not the certificate.

Comment: I haven't tried `ntfsdecrypt` myself yet -- so it's good to know that the procedure *should* work.

Comment: What decrypt procedure were you referring to?

Comment: I was going by another person telling me that they were unable to decipher with the cipher.exe tool, but I'll follow:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc512680(v=technet.10)   first to see how that goes.  I can do that from another Windows machine provided that I have all the private keys and certs?